# What is this time format? (10 digits, 5 decimals)

Tags: time, websocket, time-format

So a website that I'm using has a websocket and they provide the broadcast time in the following manner:

```
"broadcasted_at":1574325570.71308
```

What is this time format and how do they generate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Unix epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)  ... *the number of seconds that have elapsed since the Unix epoch, that is the time 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970*

```
now            :      1574327074 : Thu Nov 21 03:04:34 2019
start of day   :      1574316000 : Thu Nov 21 00:00:00 2019
1574325570     :      1574325570 : Thu Nov 21 02:39:30 2019
```

convert online : https://www.epochconverter.com/

... or download code (to build) to have command line program to perform the conversion https://github.com/darrenjs/c_dev_utils

I'm guessing the fractional part is the number of microseconds within the current second.

Comment: Since there are more than 3 decimals, the granularity is finer than milliseconds (which wold be 3 decimals). But it’s got to be fractional seconds, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

> … and how do they generate it?

I don’t know, of course, what language or libraries your website is using. So this is just an example. To generate a value like 1574325570.71308 in Java:

```
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    double epochSeconds = now.getEpochSecond()
            + (double) now.getNano() / (double) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1);
    String result = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%f", epochSeconds);
    System.out.println("result: " + result);
```

When I ran this snippet just now (2019-12-15T11:18:01.562699Z), the output was:

> result: 1576408681.562699

If you want exactly 5 decimals always another way is to use a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS)
            .appendPattern(".SSSSS")
            .toFormatter();
    String result = formatter.format(now);
```

> result: 1576408681.56269